# How to get a JSON without escape characters in Spring Boot Response?

Tags: json, spring-boot, response

According to my requirement i have to keep this JSON hard coded as a String in my service class like this.

```
String sample = " {\"menu\": {\n" +
            "  \"id\": \"file\",\n" +
            "  \"value\": \"File\",\n" +
            "  \"popup\": {\n" +
            "    \"menuitem\": [\n" +
            "      {\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},\n" +
            "      {\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},\n" +
            "      {\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}}";
```

So that i Have a controller in which have to give this JSON as a Response .

```
@RequestMapping(value = '''')
public Response rechargeRequestResponseMatcher(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

     try{
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sample);
        String jsonString = jsonObj.toString();
        response.setResponseBody(jsonString );
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
     :
    }
```

If i call this using postman ResponseBody with escapes. Like this.

[image]

Why this and how to get only the JSON without as such.

Thanks,

Comment: Try adding @ResponseBody annotation to your method

Comment: Same Response. I think What is doing with the @ResponseBody can do the same for with RestController Annotation

Comment: If you only want to get rid of Escape characters try `sample.replaceAll("\n","");`
and `sample.replaceAll("\","");`

Comment: This is okay for a String not for the Postman String as i showed in the above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the suggestions above not working, you can do another try:

1. redesign your response class resembling the sample response your have
   shown here
2. deserialize your json object to that response class
3. return that class.
   Hope that will work:
   example:

   public class Response{

   ```
        private String status;
        private String message;
        private ResponseBody responseBody;
       //standard setters getters

   }

   public class ResponseBody{
         private Menu menu;      
         //setters getters
   }

   public class Menu{
         private String id;
         private String value;
         private Popup popup;
         //setters getters
   }

   public class Popup{
         private List<Menuitem>menuitem;
         //setters getters
   }
   public class Menuitem{
         private String value;
         private String  onclick;
         //setters getters
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes This Work. I did the same finally. Thanks. But Do you know why is that?

Comment: in your code, you have set the sample response json string as `string` in responseBody which got delivered without escaping the backslash. Just treating as string while assigning to the response class. I think that's why

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, you should either make your controller a **RestController** or if you don't want your entire controller to be RestController you can annotate specific method as **@ResponseBody**. If you still do not want either of these two, try doing this,

> please note that I am using **HttpServletResponse responses** for this example

```
response.setResponseBody(sample ); //add the string directly
response.setStatus(200); //set status explicitly
```

I hope this will work otherwise use the actual beauty of Spring boot and make your controller a **RestController**

Comment: @ljhar , I have annotated controller as RestController. Im not returning type HttpServletResponse rather than Custom type of Response. I pass the String directly but the result is same.